# Error: "Origin file:// is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin." when load from local file with WkWebView (WebKit)

Tags: javascript, ios, swift, iphone, ios14

This's my code when loadUrl (file from local) with WkWebview but error like capture screen
My local html file work with UIWebView.
Please help me, Thank!

```
private func loadUrl(_ symbol : String) {
        webView.isHidden = true
        webView?.configuration.preferences.setValue(true, forKey: "allowFileAccessFromFileURLs")
        webView?.configuration.setValue(true, forKey: "allowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs")
        webView?.configuration.setValue(true, forKey: "_allowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs")
        webView?.configuration.preferences.javaScriptEnabled = true
        showLoading()
        webView.stopLoading()
        guard let bundle = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "mobile", ofType: "html", inDirectory: "DChart") else {
            return
        }
        let url = URL(fileURLWithPath: bundle)
        let urlString = url.absoluteString
        let language = UserDefaultsApp.readLang()
        var queryString = String(format: "?update=%@&symbol=%@&language=%@","true", symbol,language)
        if AppData.isDerivativeSymbol(symbol: symbol) {
            queryString = String(format: "?update=%@&symbol=%@&language=%@","true", Utils.getNameForChartDer(symbol: symbol),language)
        }
        guard let finalUrl = URL(string: (urlString +  queryString)) else {
            return
        }
        Log.d("DChart \(urlString) \(finalUrl.absoluteString)")
        webView.navigationDelegate = self
        webView.loadFileURL(finalUrl, allowingReadAccessTo: url)
    }
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: you can't use XMLHttpRequest to load `file:///` resources - you need to be serving your code using an HTTP server

Comment: @JaromandaX but if I use UIWebview, it still work